# Difference between BiFunction<X, X> and BinaryOperator<X>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, functional-interface

I am not able to understand that how come `BinaryOperator<Integer>` could be placed at the place of `A` in the code below, but not `BiFunction<Integer, Integer>`?

```
A foo = (a, b) -> { return a * a + b * b; };
int bar = foo.apply(2, 3);
System.out.println(bar);
```

Could someone please help me understand it.

Comment: probably because its `BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>` and not `BiFunction<Integer, Integer>` that you've given a try.... also if you look at the BinaryOperator itself, it reads `BinaryOperator<T> extends BiFunction<T,T,T>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`BinaryOperator` is a special `BiFunction`. So you can assign the same expression to both of them. Check this out.

```
BinaryOperator<Integer> foo = (a, b) -> {
    return a * a + b * b;
};
BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> barFn = (a, b) -> {
    return a * a + b * b;
};
```

If you look at the source code, it would be

```
public interface BinaryOperator<T> extends BiFunction<T,T,T> {
   // Remainder omitted.
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but it's probably because the question asks why it's not possible. You have incidentally answered the question by including the missing type parameter in your usage of `BiFunction`.

Answer (score 3):

The Bifunction and the BinaryOperator are same but the only difference here is the argument type and the return type of interfaces.

Consider a case where you want to concatenate two strings and return the result. In this case, you can choose either one of them but BinaryOperator is a good choice to go with because if you focus on the arguments and the return type, they all are the same.

```
BinaryOperator<String> c=(str,str1)->str+str1;
```

you can do the same with Bifunction but now see the difference here:

```
BiFunction<String,String,String> c=(str,str1)->str+str1;
```

Now consider a case in which we want to add two integers and return a string. Here we can only choose the BiFunction and not the BinaryOperator:

```
BiFunction<Integer,Integer,String> c=(a,b)->"Answer="+(a+b);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at `BinaryOperator` code you will see that `BinaryOperator` has been extended `BiFunction` which means `BinaryOperator` is a special kind of `BiFunction`.

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface BinaryOperator<T> extends BiFunction<T,T,T> {
    // interface implementation
}
```

but the main difference is that when you use `BinaryOperator` your two inputs and return type is the same.
here is an example of `BinaryOperator` and `BiFunction` to get more of it:

```java
BinaryOperator<Integer> sum = (a, b) -> a + b;
BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> sum2 = (a, b) -> a + b;
```

a better way to use BinaryOperator if you want to use java's primitive data type there has been some functional interface to have a good experience and get rid of boxing thing: `IntBinaryOperator` & `LongBinaryOperator` & `DoubleBinaryOperator`.
and finally you can write above code like this:

```java
IntBinaryOperator sum = (a, b) -> a + b;
// OR use method reference like bellow
IntBinaryOperator sum = Integer::sum;
```